# flask + marshmallow schema complains 'missing data for required field'

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, marshmallow

I have a simple flask server (with no sqlalchemy at this stage) and it is unable to parse request for a mandatory field

Server python code -->

```
from flask import request, jasonify, make_response, abort
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class MySchema(Schema):
      ref_date=fields.Str(required=True)

schema_instance = MySchema()
@app.route('/functions/regression',method=['GET'])
def perform_regression():
     print('ref_date: ', request.args.get('ref_date'))
     errors = schema_instance.validate(request.form)
     if errors:
         abort(400, str(errors))

app.run()
```

I have a client python code as follows -->

```
import requests
res = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/functions/regression?ref_date='20200205'")
print(res.status_code, res.text)
```

I am always getting error message "Missing data for required field".

Any pointers? I do get the parameters correctly on the server as can be seen with `request.args.get()` but after this Schema returns the error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on suggestion of Igor, the following works

```
from flask import request, jasonify, make_response, abort
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class MySchema(Schema):
    ref_date=fields.Str(required=True)

schema_instance = MySchema()
@app.route('/functions/regression',method=['GET'])
def perform_regression():
    print('ref_date: ', request.args.get('ref_date'))
    errors = schema_instance.validate(request.args) #<--fix here
    if errors:
        abort(400, str(errors))

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Serializer expects your data to be in request payload, not in request parameters.

So, you have two options:

1. Instead of GET, use PUT or POST request and put data in payload (as `{"ref_date": "20200205"}`)
2. In your method, put request parameters into some dictionary and use it instead of `request.form`.

Basically, the problem is that `request.form` has no data, so serializer throws error about missing required field.

Comment: Thanks @Igor. Based on your comment I realised that I need to pass a dictionary and I am creating this url manually (and data is not coming from a form), so the dictionary to pass is request.args